# Spring beans property binding error

Tags: spring-mvc

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'workingTimeController' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/tracker-servlet.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Validator [de.intec.tracker.controller.WorkingTimeController@4610fa] does not support command class [de.intec.tracker.dto.WorkingTimeDTO]

The Working Controller is the controller classs in java

Comment: <bean id="workingTimeController" class="de.intec.tracker.controller.WorkingTimeController">
  <property name="commandName" value="workingTimeDTO"/>
  <property name="commandClass" value="de.intec.tracker.dto.WorkingTimeDTO"/>
  <property name="formView" value="workingtime"/>
  <property name="successView" value="workingtime"/>
  <property name="validator"><ref bean="workingTimeController" /></property>
  <property name="workingTimeBo" ref="workingTimeBo"/>
  <property name="userBo" ref="userBo"/>
 </bean>When I put the validator tag in comment run fine but as soon as i remove comment err occur

Comment: Which controller are u using?Show some code

Comment: public class WorkingTimeController
    extends SimpleFormController implements Validator

Answer (score 0):

Your can define like below  code snippet

LoginFormCommand
    com.aims.commands.LoginFormCommand

and validator should using validator interface like below code snippet

public class LoginFormValidator implements Validator {

```
public boolean supports(Class arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return LoginFormCommand.class.equals(arg0);

}

public void validate(Object obj, Errors errors) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    LoginFormCommand login = (LoginFormCommand) obj;
    System.out.println("validate==============");
    ValidationUtils.rejectIfEmpty(errors,"username","field.required", "Required field");
    ValidationUtils.rejectIfEmpty(errors,"password","field.required", "Required field");
    }
```

}